# "Gluing" HTML to an image

Tags: css

Here's my dilemma, I've got a background image that has a bar on it.  I fit the background image by using

```
body {
     background-image: url("foo");
     background-size: 100%;
}
```

I also have some html that I want to be *inside* that bar.  The problem is, when the user resizes the browser window, the image adjusts to fit it (which is what I want it to do) but the html stays in the same spot, so it gets put outside the bar.  Is there a way I can make my html resizable like the image so that it appears that the html is *glued* to the image?  Can somebody give me a css clip for this?

Comment: How complex is this "bar", can't you create a div to mimic it?

Comment: Make the bar it's own div, and give the elements inside of it a relative height/width, and the bar a width of 100%, so that when it resizes, the image and the content change sizes. You could probably do the same with margins.

Comment: Please create a testcase of your problem.

Comment: Sorry, I'll create one and edit the question, may be a sec...

Comment: Sorry to put this simple question here, never had to use an image in a question.  How can I upload an image for my question?

Comment: http://imgur.com and then use the Image button on the SO entry editor (`From internet` selection in the popup).

Comment: You can also use http://jsfiddle.net to create a demo with live code, which is the preferred method to a screencap in this case.

Comment: Thanks. Can upload sometime tonight or tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest problem with using images to guide your layouts is exemplified by this issue. Unfortunately, Harrison, you there is no solution that will enable you to do what you want across browsers or browser sizes without changing the image. If you can, please post a screenshot of what it is supposed to look like so that we can help you modify your background to improve its compatibility

In the meantime, I suggest that you remove the bar from the image and continue to use the image as your background. Then use a div with `display: block;` and use the bar as its background.

Comment: ...aren't div's inherently `block` styled?

Comment: yes they are, but because one of the other posts said that he should change the width to 100% I thought I'd confirm that he had divs set to `display: block` in case he was overriding the default display style

Answer (score 0):

If you want the bar to be resizable, set its height and width to percentage amounts of the container height and width. Of course, when the window is reduced in size to a large extent, the HTML would spill out, there's no remedy for that.

Comment: Is there a different way I could do this then?

Comment: Not really. Perhaps there are ways to detect browser resize by Javascript, through that you can simultaneously adjust the font-size as well so that the content does not spill out, but that would break graceful degradation, as users with Javascript disabled won't get the advantage. Plus it will be complicated enough, not sure whether it will be worth it.

Comment: How can I size the background smaller without using percentages of browser size?

Comment: Unfortunately `top: 0; left: 0;` isn't the same in all browsers, nor do all browsers render pixels as exactly the same size. As odd as it may sound, it happens to be true and because of it the position of your elements will not be the same in all browsers, even if you are using percentages. You are trying to put a band-aid on a gushing wound - better to do it right and do it with compatibility in mind.

Comment: Yeah, of course pixel size depends on browser and zoom level, but since we are specifying 0, I think it won't matter, for 0 remains 0 whatever be the pixel dimensions!

Comment: @Harrison, you should not rely on `background-size`, it's browser support is limited. Instead, you can mimic it the hard way: http://webdesign.about.com/od/css3/f/blfaqbgsize.htm